# How to fit a negative binominal model to data using maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: python, statistics, curve-fitting, data-fitting, binomial-theorem

I am trying to fit a negative binominal distribution to a dataset that only has one field and that field is the number of words in a sentence. How do I fit the distribution using statsmodels.discrete.discrete_mode

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation? https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.DiscreteModel.html

Comment: if i have my data as exog then what endog if the dataset only has one field ?

Comment: If you just want to fit the distribution without explanatory variables, then `endog` are the observed values of the distribution and `exog` is a constant, i.e. array of `ones`. Parameters are (log)mean and dispersion, and not the standard negative binomial parameterization.

Answer (score 2):

I think that statsmodels class is just meant to be a backend asset for regression models, and not for fitting distributions. See the reference here: [Regression with Discrete Dependent Variable](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/discretemod.html)

But in an answer in an [other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451222/in-scipy-stats-rv-continuous-has-a-fit-method-to-find-mles-but-rv-discrete-does), there is a link, with a possible workaround to exploit the statsmodels regression model, to fit your distribution: [Newbie question about discrete distributions and MLE](https://groups.google.com/g/pystatsmodels/c/GZ8kXoFitn0/m/9ve8GVOwl1kJ?pli=1)

I have looked at [scipy.stats.nbinom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nbinom.html#scipy.stats.nbinom) as well for you, as scipy has the MLE fitting methods for all kinds of distributions. But the discrete distributions do not have fitting methods.
There are numerous answers here explaining the difficulties with that, and some alternative approaches:

- [In scipy.stats rv_continuous has a fit method to find MLEs, but rv_discrete does not. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451222/in-scipy-stats-rv-continuous-has-a-fit-method-to-find-mles-but-rv-discrete-does)
- [Fitting negative binomial in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816522/fitting-negative-binomial-in-python)
- [Fitting For Discrete Data: Negative Binomial, Poisson, Geometric Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308441/fitting-for-discrete-data-negative-binomial-poisson-geometric-distribution)

As an alternative possibility besides the ones mentioned in the above answers, I can advise you to check out Bayesian numerical methods with the [PyMC3 package](https://docs.pymc.io/), as that includes a [Negative Binomial](https://docs.pymc.io/api/distributions/discrete.html#pymc3.distributions.discrete.NegativeBinomial) distribution as well.